# Web scraping website with BeautifulSoup and Selenium won't detect table elements in webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to retrieve the table containing tenders in the following website:
https://wbgeconsult2.worldbank.org/wbgec/index.html#$h=1582042296662
(After clicking link, would need to click on 'Business Opportunities' at the top right to get to the table)

I tried using pandas read_html, Selenium and BeautifulSoup, all of which failed (they simply don't detect the table elements at all).
I also tried to find a link in the networks tab of the dev tools, but none of them seem to work.
Is this even possible? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
import re

URL='https://wbgeconsult2.worldbank.org/wbgec/index.html#$h=1582042296662'

#Enter Gecko driver path
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path ='/Users/****/geckodriver')

driver.get(URL)
# driver.minimize_window()

opp_path='//*[@id="menu_publicads"]/a'
list_ch=driver.find_element_by_xpath(opp_path)
ActionChains(driver).click(list_ch).perform()
time.sleep(5)

sort_xpath='//*[@id="jqgh_selection_notification.publication_date"]'
list_ch=driver.find_element_by_xpath(sort_xpath)
ActionChains(driver).click(list_ch).perform()
time.sleep(5)

sort_xpath='//*[@id="jqgh_selection_notification.publication_date"]'
list_ch=driver.find_element_by_xpath(sort_xpath)
ActionChains(driver).click(list_ch).perform()
time.sleep(5)

re=requests.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(re.content,'lxml')
row=soup.findAll('td')
print(row)


ti=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')
for t in ti:
    print(ti.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL via XML request. You can use this example how to load and parse the data into a DataFrame:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://wbgeconsult2.worldbank.org/wbgect/gwproxy"
data = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><GetCurrentPublicNotifications xmlns="http://cordys.com/WBGEC/DBT_Selection_Notification/1.0"><NotifTypeId3 xmlns="undefined">3</NotifTypeId3><DS type="dsort"><selection_notification.eoi_deadline order="asc"></selection_notification.eoi_deadline></DS></GetCurrentPublicNotifications></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, "xml")

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(soup.prettify())

data = []
for sn in soup.select("SELECTION_NOTIFICATION"):
    d = {}
    for tag in sn.find_all(recursive=False):
        d[tag.name] = tag.get_text(strip=True)
    data.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
        ID       PUBLICATION_DATE                   EOI_DEADLINE LANGUAGE_OF_NOTICE        ADVERTISE_UNTIL                                              TITLE SELECTION_TYPE_NAME SELECTION_TYPE_ID SELECTION_NUMBER SOLICITATION_OR_FRAMEWORK SELECTION_STATUS_ID SELECTION_SUB_STATUS_ID
0   148625  2021-04-16T00:00:00.0  2021-04-26T23:59:59.900000000            English  2021-04-26T23:59:59.0               Zanzibar PPP Diagnostic and Pipeline                Firm                 2          1274225                                             2                       8
1   148536  2021-04-14T00:00:00.0  2021-04-26T23:59:59.900000000            English  2021-04-26T23:59:59.0  Assessment of Institutional Capacity for Imple...                Firm                 2          1274123                                             2                       8
2   148310  2021-04-12T00:00:00.0  2021-04-26T23:59:59.900000000            English  2021-04-26T23:59:59.0                         Albania Digital Jobs Pilot                Firm                 2          1273851                                             2                       8
3   148399  2021-04-12T00:00:00.0  2021-04-26T23:59:59.900000000            English  2021-04-26T23:59:59.0  EaP - Green Financing for Transport Infrastruc...                Firm                 2          1273953                                             2                       8
4   148448  2021-04-12T00:00:00.0  2021-04-26T23:59:59.900000000            English  2021-04-26T23:59:59.0  Surveying LGBTI people in North Macedonia and ...                Firm                 2          1274001                                             2                       8
5   148277  2021-04-14T00:00:00.0  2021-04-26T23:59:59.900000000            English  2021-04-26T23:59:59.0             SME FINANCE FORUM 2021 WEBSITES REVAMP                Firm                 2          1273810                                             2                       8

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Wow this is fantastic!!! thank you so much!!! Didn't know about this until now!  How would I be able to retrieve the data link in the future if i run into a similar issue? Is it in the Network tab?

Comment: I also didn't understand the soup.select("SELECTION_NOTIFICATION"), i thought soup.select was for CSS selectors only ? how did you get the SELECTION_NOTIFICATION? Thanks again!

Comment: @zaza001 Yes, you can see this request in the network tab. With CSS selectors you can select HTML and XML. It's universal :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This code will wait till the element appears and then grab text. Edit this code according to your need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get('https://wbgeconsult2.worldbank.org/wbgec/index.html#$h=1582042296662')
BusinessOpportunity = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()=\"Business Opportunities\"]"))).click()

TableRow = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id=\"notificationsGrid\"]/descendant::tr")))

for row in TableRow:
    print(row.text)
```